# Xlsx sheetname exceeding 31 characters in length in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, xlsx

I'm using react to get table data from database and exporting it as excel and making the title of excel as tablename. But I'm facing and issue if the excel file name is exceeding 31 characters, sheet is not getting downloaded. And throwing below error in browser console output.

```
Uncaught Error: Sheet names cannot exceed 31 chars
```

Here is my code below

```
var workbook=XLSX.utils.book_new();
workbook.SheetNames.push(title); //title: tablename
var workSheet=XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tableData); //tableData: data from Database
workbook.Sheets[title]=workSheet;
var output=XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType:'xlsx', type:'binary'});
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(output)], {type:"application/octet-stream"}), title + '.xlsx');
```

Edit:
I don't want to change the sheetname. Just wanted react to download even if sheetnames exceeding 31 characters

Comment: What's your table name?  The bottom line is, 31 characters is a hard ceiling for the length of a sheet name.  I don't know the React side of things but this here ... workbook.Sheets[title]=workSheet ... the "workSheet" object is likely waaaaaay more than 31 characters.  Why don't you change it to this ... workbook.Sheets[title]='Test' ... and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried it. But when it is giving me empty excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing following changes

```
var workbook=XLSX.utils.book_new();
//workbook.SheetNames.push(title); //title: tablename
var workSheet=XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tableData); //tableData: data from Database
//workbook.Sheets[title]=workSheet;
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, workSheet, "Test"); // This line solve the problem
var output=XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType:'xlsx', type:'binary'});
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(output)], {type:"application/octet-stream"}), title + '.xlsx');
```